# Sandbox Expiration Email

Tags: deployment, sandbox

As per [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_licenses.htm&type=5), users with Manage Sandbox permission will receive a notification email before sandboxes get deleted due to inactivity or being locked for a certain period of time.

> When you exceed your sandbox allocations, the appropriate number of sandboxes are locked to restore your license compliance, starting
> with the least recently used sandboxes. After you meet compliance, the
> most recently used locked sandboxes are unlocked. If you do nothing,
> sandboxes locked for more than 60 days are deleted and can’t be
> recovered. Users with Manage Sandbox permission receive at least three
> email notifications over 60 days before sandboxes are deleted.

Is this sent to the users with Manage Sandbox permission in Production, or in that specific sandbox?

I assume that this permission would be set up in production and then copied over to the newly generated sandboxes, so if any sandbox is about to expire, all these users get a notification. This could pose a risk in case a beginner admin disables these permissions in a newly generated sandbox. However, if the beginner admin did the same for the production, no-one would receive the notifications for any sandboxes, so I assume that it is more secure for the email notification to be driven by Manage Sandbox permissions for each sandbox individually, not collectively for the production.

Can't test, this any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

[Technically](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_inactive_sandbox_expiration.htm&type=5), Users who have the Manage Sandbox permission in the production org (and have not opted out of sandbox expiration emails) are notified prior to scheduling the sandbox for deletion. I just received such an email for a Sandbox. The email looks like this (as of May 2023):

> One or more of your sandboxes are about to expire for org ID, xxxxx`

> Dear Salesforce Admin, We'd like to inform you that the following
> sandboxes (org ID, name, created by, last login date) have not been
> logged into for at least 90 days. According to our sandbox policy,
> sandboxes that haven't been accessed for 180 days are deleted.
>
> xxx, Partial, yyyy@salesforce.com.zzz, Feb 18, 2023
>
> To retain access to your sandbox, any active user can log in with
> their sandbox login credentials at https://test.salesforce.com or
> access the sandbox's login URL on the sandbox list page in the
> production org. You can also delete your sandbox if it is no longer
> required.
>
> To opt out of receiving email notifications for future sandbox
> expirations for this production org, you can suspend email
> notifications. From Setup, select Dev Hub, then click the Enabled
> toggle for Sandbox Expiration Email Opt Out.
>
> How do I get more information? See "Inactive Sandbox Expiration" in
> Salesforce Help.